# Can't connect to Xamarin on Mac from Visual Studio

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.ios

I have Xamarin installed both on my Visual Studio 2015 and my MacBook Pro with OS X 10.11.4. The problem is that when I try to connect from VS to OS X, it says that for some reason it can't start the Designer agent.

As far as I see from the log the main problem is in this:

```
Xamarin.VisualStudio.IOS.MacServer Error: 0 : [2016-04-03 21:21:44.1336] An error occured starting the Designer 4.0.3.214 agent: Xamarin.Messaging.Client.AgentConsoleRunner Information: 0 : ==== :: Xamarin :: 4.0.3.214-cycle6-c6sr3+0dd817c ====
Xamarin.Messaging.Client.AgentConsoleRunner Information: 0 : Starting Designer 4.0.3.214...
Failed-Native type size mismatch between Xamarin.Mac.dll and the executing architecture. Xamarin.Mac.dll was built for 32-bit, while the current process is 64-bit.
```

Is there any way to fix it? Btw, here is the full log http://pastebin.com/iB6X0XWe

Comment: @Dominic Yes, here is VS info http://pastebin.com/mNGsKRjG and here is  Xamarin Studio http://pastebin.com/a8kZRJPF

Answer (score 0):

I see a number of issues in that log. One that caught my eye is that it failed to download provisioning profiles. Make sure that XCode is installed (and up to date) and that you can run it. You might also need to log in to the Apple dev portal and accept a license agreement - sometimes the portal will block some actions if there is a pending agreement.

Also, it looks like your Xamarin install on OSX might be slightly different (or might be on different channel):

> There is a mismatch between the installed Xamarin.iOS (version 9.6.1.9) on the Mac MacBook-Pro-Andrey.local (192.168.0.3) and the local Xamarin.iOS 9.6.1.8. While this may not be an issue, it might cause unexpected behaviors. When applying updates, make sure to keep both the Mac and Windows in sync.

I would fix that first before doing anything else.

Comment: They both are on the same update channel(Stable) and I'm checking for updates all the time and every time I see that software doesn't have any new updates. XCode is up to date, running nice, dev portal doesn't show me any new license agreement, but I downloaded all provisioning profiles to XCode manually and there is no error now.

Comment: When you say that "there is no error now", is your problem solved? Are you able to build iOS projects from Visual Studio now?

Comment: No, I meant that there is no error about provisioning, but still Designer agent is not starting

Comment: Line 44 from that latest log is definitely where it is failing now. Instead of that error message you should be seeing "Agent Designer 4.0.3.214 is running", which is what happens for me. That's a really odd error message - Visual Studio is a 32-bit app so it shouldn't be trying to load 64-bit libraries. What version of Windows are you running? And what version of Visual Studio? And do you have *any* extensions installed other than Xamarin?

Comment: I'm running 64 bit Windows 10 Pro with VS 2015 Enterprise and here is the full VS info about it's extensions and version http://pastebin.com/zb8h74KX
I also did notice that line 44, but can't get any idea why this happens. In task manager I see that VS is running 32-bit